# SQL Split column into X number of columns then insert to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table which consists of 1 column. Each entry has an X number of a delimiter. I want to split this into X+1 columns using the delimiter and insert it into another table which is already created and contains x+1 columns but contains no entries.

For example for table 1 I'd have
column1

```
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d
```

so I'd want to insert the following to table 2 (which would already have the right number of columns)

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
1   2   3   4
a   b   c   d
```

I have a solution to this but it's  far too inefficient (took about 5 minutes to do just 10 columns).

I start off by adding a row number to table 1 and populating it then I would add a row number column to table 2 then insert all the row numbers from table 2 to table 1.

Then I'd run the following loop:

```
DECLARE @DELIMITER NVARCHAR(10) = ',',
@columns nvarchar(max) ='Column1,column2,column3,column4', 
@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@table nvarchar(100) = 'dbo.test'

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN


IF(@columns LIKE '%' +@DELIMITER +'%')
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE A 
SET A.[' +SUBSTRING(@columns,0,CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@columns)) +'] =SUBSTRING(B.FULLTABLE,0,CHARINDEX('''+@DELIMITER+''',B.FULLTABLE))
FROM ' + @TABLE + ' A
INNER JOIN #FULLTABLE B ON B.ROW_NUMBER = A.ROW_NUMBER
SELECT  FROM #FULLTABLE'

EXEC(@SQL)
SET @columns = SUBSTRING(@columns,1+CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@columns),LEN(@columns))

UPDATE #FULLTABLE
SET FULLTABLE = SUBSTRING(FULLTABLE,1+CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,FULLTABLE),LEN(FULLTABLE))
END

ELSE 
BEGIN 
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE A 
SET A.[' +@columns +'] =B.FULLTABLE
FROM ' + @TABLE + ' A
INNER JOIN #FULLTABLE B ON B.ROW_NUMBER = A.ROW_NUMBER
SELECT  FROM #FULLTABLE'

EXEC(@SQL)
BREAK
END


END
```

note that I usually don't hardcode in the value for "columns" it's automatically generated based on the table I'm working with but I just hardcoded it here to make it clearer as to what I'm trying to do.

Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

the function to convert string to table . if you give @input='1,2,3,4'
it returns 
table
value1      value2        value3         value4
1              2             3             4

```
    create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_listtotable1](@input AS nVarchar(max))
    RETURNS
    @Result TABLE(Value1 INT,Value2 INT,Value3 INT,Value4 INT)
  AS
      BEGIN
       DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20)
      DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(20)
       DECLARE @str2 VARCHAR(20)
       DECLARE @str3 VARCHAR(20)
       DECLARE @ind Int
       IF(@input is not null)
         BEGIN
        SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)

              SET @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
             SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
              INSERT INTO @Result(Value1) values (@str)
              SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)

              SET @str1 = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
             SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
             update @Result 
             set Value2 = (@str1) where Value1=@str
              SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)

              SET @str2 = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
             SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
               update @Result 
             set Value3 = (@str2) where Value1=@str
              SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)


        SET @str3 = @input
         update @Result 
             set Value4 = (@str3) where Value1=@str
  END
  RETURN
```

END

put the following into loop ,

```
     insert into table1(column1, column2,column3,column4) 
         select * from [fn_listtotable1]( @string)
```

Comment: It appears there can be n values in the string not just/always 4.

Comment: it is just for 4values

Comment: Perhaps I misread the question: but I interpret "Each entry has an X number of a delimiter." to mean it's variable; and the example provided was just that but with n/x number of entries possible.  Thus setting str1,str2,str3,str limits to only 4.  But perhaps the example represents that it will always be 4.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit unclear on the ask and if you could let me know

- is there multiple lines of data in each Row
- does the above row contain a header
- a mocked-sample of two rows of data

I am guessing this is what you ask is. I assume you are using SQL Server 2016 and above (if not see note below to replace string_split)

```
CREATE TABLE OneColumn  (
    MyDelimitedColumn NVARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO OneColumn (MyDelimitedColumn)
VALUES 
    ('Col1,Col2,Col3')
,   ('x,y,z')
,   ('1,2,3,4,5,6')


SELECT 
MyDelimitedColumn,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MyDelimitedColumn) as RowKey,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MyDelimitedColumn ORDER BY MyDelimitedColumn) as ColumnKey,
value as ColValue
FROM OneColumn
CROSS APPLY string_split(MyDelimitedColumn,',')
```

This would result in

```
MyDelimitedColumn|RowKey|ColumnKey|ColValue
1,2,3,4,5,6      |1     |1        |1
1,2,3,4,5,6      |1     |2        |2
1,2,3,4,5,6      |1     |3        |3
1,2,3,4,5,6      |1     |4        |4
1,2,3,4,5,6      |1     |5        |5
1,2,3,4,5,6      |1     |6        |6
a,b,c,d,e        |2     |1        |a
a,b,c,d,e        |2     |2        |b
a,b,c,d,e        |2     |3        |c
a,b,c,d,e        |2     |4        |d
a,b,c,d,e        |2     |5        |e
x,y,z            |3     |1        |x
x,y,z            |3     |2        |y
x,y,z            |3     |3        |z
```

Once you have the above result-set you could do a dynamic pivot to convert the rows into columns.

If you are using an older version of SQL server, just implement any one of these `string_split` equivalent function

https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

A full example

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ResultSet') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ResultSet

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OneColumn') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE #OneColumn  (
    MyDelimitedColumn NVARCHAR(1000)
)
TRUNCATE TABLE #OneColumn  

INSERT INTO #OneColumn (MyDelimitedColumn)
VALUES 
    ('Col1,Col2,Col3')
,   ('x,y,z')
,   ('1,2,3,4,5,6')


SELECT 
MyDelimitedColumn,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MyDelimitedColumn) as RowKey,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MyDelimitedColumn ORDER BY MyDelimitedColumn) as ColumnKey,
value as ColValue
INTO #ResultSet
FROM #OneColumn
CROSS APPLY string_split(MyDelimitedColumn,',')


DECLARE @MaxRowKey INT       ,
        @I INT = 1           ,
        @DySQL NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @PivotCols NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @MaxRowKey= MAX(RowKey) FROM #ResultSet

WHILE @I <= @MaxRowKey
BEGIN

    -- REPLACE STRING_AGG with FOR_XML PATH Method (https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)
    SET @PivotCols = (SELECT DISTINCT STRING_AGG(quotename(ColumnKey),',') FROM #ResultSet WHERE RowKey = @I)

    SET @DySQL = N'
    SELECT pvt.*
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT * FROM 
        #ResultSet 
    WHERE RowKey = '+cast(@i as Nvarchar(100))+'
    ) p
    PIVOT 
    (
        MAX(P.ColValue) FOR p.ColumnKey IN ('+@PivotCols+')
    ) as Pvt
    '

    EXEC (@dysql)




    SET @I = @I + 1
END
```